# Entity Framework and SQL Server Compact Edition group by DefaultIfEmpty error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I write a select statement in EF, it executes well when I use SQL Server Express as database. But when I change my database to SQL Server CE edition, the following error occurs:

> A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement

My code:

```
(from r1 in _db.Products
 join r2 in _db.SaleDetails on r1.ID equals r2.PID into g
 from r2 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
 group new { r1, r2 } by r1.Code.Substring(0, _Group.Code.Length + 3) into g
 select new
        {
            GroupCode = g.OrderBy(p => p.r1.Code.Length).FirstOrDefault().r1,
            Sum1 = g.Where(p => p.r2.IsMain).Select(p2 => p2.r2.Fee).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
            Sum2 = g.Where(p => !p.r2.IsMain).Select(p2 => p2.r2.Fee).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Sounds like query provider issue. What happens if you comment out the `Sum1 = ...` and `Sum2 = ..` lines - still getting the error?

Comment: the error was happened

Comment: Hmm, what *parameter* it could be. What is `_Group.Code.Length`? Or try removing it from the query, e.g. `Substring(0, 3)` just to see if it's causing the error, and then look for a solution.

Comment: I think that it's a generated query issue. Probably the EF provider for sqlcompact has a bug. If this is the case, the fast way to solve the problem is to change the query (for example adding a ToList somewhere if you have small data).

Comment: Capture the generated SQL for starters (using _db.Database.Log)